# I do not know which part of coding I did wrong about Python

Tags: python

Write a Python function arctan() which takes an input argument (parameter) x and
computes the sum of the first 11 terms in the following infinite sum:
-[arctan(1/x)= 1/x - 1/3x^3 + 1/5x^5 - 1/7x^7 + 1/9x^9]

The final term in your sum should therefore be 1/21x^21

Test your function using the following formula:
-[pi/4 = 4arctan(1/5) - arctan(1/239)]

Hints:
i) if your function arctan() is implemented correctly, the magnitude of the difference between 4 (4 arctan(1/5) − arctan(1/239)) and numpy.pi should be smaller than
10−15
ii) your function should take input x and compute arctan(1/x). Because of equation (5),
your test code should therefore call arctan() as follows:
4∗(4∗ a r c ta n ( 5 ) − a r c ta n (239 ) )

Below is my code but I do not know which part I did wrong need you help please?

```
import numpy as np

sumA = 0
def arctan(x):
    for i in range(0,11,2):
        sumA = sumA + [1/(i*x**i)]
        return sumA
print(arctan(1))

sumB = 0
def arctan(x):
    for i in range(0,11,2):
        sumB = sumB - [1/(i*x**i)]
        return sumB
print(arctan(2))

Sum = 0
for i in range(0,11,1):
    sum = sumA - sumB
print(sum)
```

Can someone helping me to solve this question due to I do not know which part I did wrong thanks

Comment: Please consider adding the output of your code.

Comment: Plenty of things wrong here. Don't use "sumA=0" outside your functiony. Just define one function that does both sums. Don't put [] around the terms, you are making them into lists. Don't loop over the last sum. Also, you are mixing up Sum and sum. And you have put return statements inside the loops.

Answer (score 0):

There are many inaccuracies in your code:

- In your function you have as variable the number `x`, that is the value for what you want to calculate the `arctan`. But you are summing on the variable `sumA`, that is also the return of your function. So if you calculate another `arctan`, it will sum over the previous result (since the part of code `sumA = 0` is not in the function and doesn't refresh each time you call it
- Other thing is the `return` of the function; you want your function to return after it completed all the cycles, so you should put it outside the for loop
- The `range` function is also wrong, if you try to print out the iterator in the `for` loop, you will see that it will give you 0,2,4,6,8,10. So, first you want to start from 1 and second, if you want to include 11, you should stop at 12, because python stop one number before the upper bound
- Other thing is mathematical, the Taylor expansion of `arctan` take only the odd exponents, not the even.
- Last thing, never call a variable with an "orange" name, such as sum,int,float,input. These are classes that you better not overwrite with your variables

  def arctan(x):
  i0 = 1
  a = x
  for i in range(3,12,2):
  i0 *= -1
  x += i0*a**i/i
  return x

Output:

```
0.7440115440115441
```

With more iterations(300):

```
0.7853814967307984
```

"Real" value:

```
np.arctan(1) = 0.7853981633974483
```